# Tracking mouse in clojurescript / reagent / reagi?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to get to grips with reagent in clojurescript with a simple drawing program.

I'm looking for an example of how to access the mouse position in a principled "FRP" inspired style with [Reagi](https://github.com/weavejester/reagi).

In various reagent examples I can see things that look like this :

```
[:p [:onmousemove (fn (evt) ...)]]
```

to attach a handler to an element of the DOM.

And to make a Reagi "behaviour" I want to write something like this :

```
(def mouse-positions (r/behavior ( ... )))
```

But how do I combine these two so that a handler I add to a DOM element feeds a Reagi behavior?

Secondly, as I'm using reagent, I'm expecting these DOM nodes to be recreated regularly. Presumably I'll need to keep rebinding the event-handler to the Reagi stream too. How do I ensure this?

cheers

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if Reagi's event stream would be better suited. Something along the lines of:

```
(defonce mouse-events (r/events {:x 0 :y 0}))

(defn home-page []
  [:div {:onMouseMove (fn [event]
                        (r/deliver mouse-events {:x (.-clientX event)
                                                 :y (.-clientY event)}))}])
```

Then, you can deref the event stream with `@mouse-events`. You shouldn't need to worry about having to rebind to the event stream as it holds the reference to it.

However, keep in mind that pushing a value into a Reagi stream will not cause Reagent to re-render a node that references it directly. For that you will need some sort of Reagent atom.

If you're creating a drawing application, I imagine your state/atom will be stored elsewhere, and you `swap!` or `reset!` that to cause the render to occur.

Also, note that both behaviors and events only hold the reference to the newest value, which may not be ideal for a drawing application. There is also Reagi's [`buffer`](http://weavejester.github.io/reagi/reagi.core.html#var-buffer) that may help with that.